Flask send_file and send_from_directory send nothing
I am at the end of dead end. I spend couple of hours just trying to send file from Flask. Run number of variants how to do it, all of them you can see bellow. And all that I manage to get it is reply like that:
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2024 16:39:23] "POST /result HTTP/1.1" 200 -
So request is correct, file is in place, but nothing happened. I try to do it locally on Mac OS and VS code, and it seems everything correct, but nothing happened. Here is my code
def generate_doc(dn, dd, pa, cr, ir):
   #with MailMerge(Template) as document:
   document = MailMerge('temp.docx')
   #print(document.get_merge_fields())

   document.merge(
       DN=dn,
       DD=dd,
       PA=pa,
       CU=cr)
   cwd = os.getcwd()
   #file_path = cwd + '/output.docx'
   file = 'output.docx'
   print(file)
   document.write(file)
   #f = BytesIO()
   #print(f)
   #document.write(f)
   #return send_file(f, 
   #                 mimetype='application/msword',
   #                 as_attachment=True, 
   #                 download_name='output.docx'
   #                 )
   try:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
            print("send file")
            #print(file)
            return send_from_directory(directory=cwd, filename="output.docx", as_attachment=True, cache_timeout=0)
            #return send_from_directory(directory=cwd, path="output.docx", as_attachment=True)
            #return send_from_directory(".", file, mimetype='application/msword', as_attachment=True, download_name='output.docx', cache_timeout=0)
            #return send_from_directory(cwd,file_path, as_attachment=True)
            #return send_file(f, mimetype='application/msword',as_attachment=True, download_name='output.docx')
            #return send_file(file_path, mimetype='application/msword',as_attachment=True, download_name='output.docx')

    else:
            return make_response(f"File '{file}' not found.", 404)
   except Exception as e:
            return make_response(f"Error: {e}", 500)

I decided to left all my variants, but not one of them is working. There is no errors, no 404 or 500 messages, always 200 and nothing. Any ideas what can be wrong with it?

Can you elaborate on "nothing happened"? What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? I presume this code is responding to HTTP queries — are you getting an empty file as a response? Any headers?

This question would benefit from a [mcve] -- code that we can run locally to reproduce the problem.

Your call to send_from_directory seems erroneous (there were both missing and unsupported parameters). The following example works for me:
import os
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def generate_doc():
    path = "examplefile.txt"
    with open(path, "w") as fd:
        fd.write("This is a test.")

    try:
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            print("send file")
            return send_from_directory(
                path=path,
                directory=os.path.dirname(path),
                as_attachment=True,
            )
        else:
            return make_response(f"File '{path}' not found.", 404)
    except Exception as e:
        return make_response(f"Error: {e}", 500)


Thank you! Your comment help me to find out error. I simple do not work properly with return result.
